# How the reset sequence is carried out in cortex m3 in case of boot code?

Tags: reset, cortex-m

After getting grip over the various fault handlers in cortex m3
Now I'm studying reset sequence and reset handler.
In normal case after power on reset. PC points to 0x00000000 where initial msp value is stored
Then at 0x00000004 reset vector is kept
Means after initializing msp reset handler is called.

In case of boot code how is the reset sequence and how the vector table is relocated after booting process

Comment: Means if I want to have boot code in my application then that boot code must initialize initial msp value, reset vector address, NMI vector address, and hard fault vector address as a part of boot code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reset sequence of the processor is the same regardless of the code that is being run. Often, boot code may choose to relocate the vector table and this is done using the "Vector Table Offset Register". The vector table can be relocated to some place in RAM or another ROM location. Boot code must at a minimum define the initial main stack pointer value, the reset vector address, the NMI vector address and the hard fault address. The last two because they can occur during the boot process.